# A counter variable in a php abstract class

Tags: php

If you have an abstract class, is there a way to keep a counter inside the abstract class to count how many times it's used?

Because if I do this:

```
abstract class abstractClassName {

    private $counter = 0;

    public function __construct() {
     $this->counter++;
   }

   public function outputCounter() {
     echo $this->counter;
   }

}

class someExtension extends abstractClassName {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

class someExtensionTwo extends abstractClassName {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

and then

```
$class = new someExtension;
$class->outputCounter();
$class2 = new someExtensionTwo;
$class2->outputCounter();
```

I get 1 twice, yet I was expecting to get 1 and then 2 on the last call, and I'm getting confused over how it's all meant to work.

Edit: changed code to reflect the real code more :)

Comment: You're not doing anything to increment the counter after you construct the object. You've only called the class once, so the number is 1.

Comment: You're only ever incrementing the `$counter` inside the constructor (which is only called using the `new` keyword in your code once).

Comment: Do you want to know how many times the counter has been used or how many times the class has been instantiated?

Comment: Thanks guys, you are right about that, but it was due to me writing a quick example, i've edited to be a truer reflection of the code involved.

Comment: "Edit: changed code to reflect the real code more" if you want us to bother do us the courtesy  of posting the actual code.

Comment: The actual code is much more complicated/long, I tried writing a very simplified version of it all to get to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wishing to keep track of how many time the class `AbstractClassName` has been instantiated, you will need to make use of static variables -- so that the value of `$this->counter` is persistent, for example:

```
abstract class abstractClassName
{
    private static $counter = 0;

    public function __construct() {
      self::$counter++;
    }

    public function outputCounter() {
     echo self::$counter;
    }
}

class someExtension extends abstractClassName
{
   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
   }
 }

class someOtherExtension extends abstractClassName
{
   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
   }
 }

$class = new someExtension;
$class->outputCounter();

$class2 = new someOtherExtension;
$class2->outputCounter();
```

Which would result in an output of: 1 & 2.